# Как запустить FTP-сервер на Android c использованием каких библиотек?(java)

Tags: java, android, сервер, ftp

Необходимо, чтобы при запуске приложения в фоновом режиме запускался FTP-сервер, чтобы уже непосредственно на этот сервер с другого устройства загружать файлы. Когда я делал приложение для Windows у меня удалось это сделать с помощью IIS(Internet Information Services), а для android все иначе, модули для скачивания и загрузки на FTP сервер сторонний реализованы, осталось только чтобы на устройстве создавался собственный ftp- сервер. Пытался сделать с помощью библиотек apache ftp server, но как выяснилось она для ОС Android не подходит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Изучите исходники FTP сервера для Android [swiftp на github](https://github.com/ppareit/swiftp)

Не рылся в кишках, но судя по манифесту все сделано на `Service` и `BroadcastReceiver`